# Show Button in Table Cell Hover Over/Mouse Over

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am building a Dashboard app in asp.net. I have placed 3 input buttons inside a div tag. When a user is moused over a table cell I would like for the buttons to show. How can I accomplish this using .css, javascript or jQuery?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<td id="bold_cell1" valign="top" width="33%" Height="33%">
    <div id="buttonBlock">
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" style="font-size:8px" />
        <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" style="font-size:8px" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" style="font-size:8px" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `DIV` inside a `td` can easily get you into size/layout problems.

Comment: Should I use a <td> in place of the div?

Comment: I would not use tables at all, specially if you have a simple template to handle. Tables are for prices :) and specifications no-one reads :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-fashioned way: CSS:

```
#buttonBlock input{
   display:none;
}
#bold_cell1:hover #buttonBlock input{
   display:block;
}
```

**[demo link](http://jsbin.com/ewolul/edit#javascript,html,live)**